# Fill Table1 With Data from Table2 Using Update Query Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Pretty straightforward question. Can I fill certain empty columns in table1 with contents from table2, using Update Query?

Been trying but without any success.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.
Hope you're all safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is possible :

```
UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.pk_id = table2.fk_id
SET table1.col1 = table2.col1;
```